# add client script to asp.net page dynamically

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I want to add javascript to asp.net page dynamically.
can anybody point me towards working example?
i know it can be done by using `Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock`
but i have no idea to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerclientscriptblock.aspx)

This is the MSDN link

```
if (!this.Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(typeof(Page), "Utils"))
        {
            string UtilsScript = ResourceHelper.GetEmbeddedAssemblyResource("Utils.js");

            this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(Page), "Utils", UtilsScript, true);
        }
```

I added the above example to help,

Here we test if the script is already registered (using the type an dkey we register against) get the script as a string from an embedded resource, then register (the last parameter of true tells the code to render Script tags).

hope this helps

P

Comment: can you explain firs and second arguemnt of the RegisterClientScriptBlock

Comment: The first is a type to "bind" the script to, in thi exampe the page, the second is a key, this is so you can test if the script exists before adding it (complex multi control environments) you test by using Pag.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(type,key) using the same type and the key used to register.

Answer (score 1):

An example to move the value of a Drop Down List to text field.  The ID parameters are the `Object.ClientID` properties for the drop down list and text box.

```
Private Sub RegisterClientDropDownToTextBox(ByVal functionName As String, ByVal dropDownId As String, ByVal textBoxId As String)
    Dim javascriptFunction As String = "function " & functionName & "() {" & _
                                       "document.getElementById('" & textBoxId & "').value = document.getElementById('" & dropDownId & "').value;" & _
                                       "}"
    Dim javascriptWireEvent As String = "document.getElementById('" & dropDownId & "').onclick = " & functionName & ";"
    Me.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), functionName & "_ScriptBlock", javascriptFunction, True)
    Me.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), functionName & "_Startup", javascriptWireEvent, True)
End Sub
```