# how to add javascript in code behind page in asp.net and C#

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am trying to add a `javascript` in to `asp.net` code behind page in `c#`.

I found some answers from this site and I have implemented that but still I am not able to call a function from `ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock()`.

Please check my code;

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string myScriptValue = "function callMe() {alert('You pressed Me!');}";
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "myScriptName", myScriptValue, true);
}
```

Please help me how to get the `callMe()` funtion in `Page_Load()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [add client script to asp.net page dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1731701/add-client-script-to-asp-net-page-dynamically)

Comment: You should user ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript instead of ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the function `callMe();` in aspx since `Page_Load` is the first to run before loading javascripts in the webpage